# Tensorflow examples for RNN

Tags: python, tensorflow, nlp, recurrent-neural-network

I am trying to implement basic NLP tasks in Tensorflow without using the build in modules as much as possible (just for learning sake)

I have been trying to implement a Part of Speech tagger using data from http://www.cnts.ua.ac.be/conll2000/chunking/

I am having a little difficulty with implementing a RNN code from scratch using an embedding layer in front and was wondering if there are examples and implementations on the same.

I have seen tons of examples using Theano and on MNIST data but havent been able to find a concrete implementation of RNNs from scratch in Tensorflow on textual data.

Any suggestions?

Comment: There's a language model (predicting the next word) example: https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/recurrent/. Might be a place to start.

Comment: it uses inbuilt cells, looking for a from scratch implementation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

after searching for a long time, I decided to do it on my own.
Here are a couple of repos I created:

[recurrent-neural-nets-tensorflow](https://github.com/roopalgarg/recurrent-neural-nets-tensorflow)

[lstm-tensorflow](https://github.com/roopalgarg/lstm-tensorflow)